# How to create Back_Log in Azur-Devops for SSIS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, ssis, sql-server-2012

I deployed SSIS packages in the recipe environment. These packages were deployed in AZUR_DEVOPS.
I want to follow the execution of these packages by creating back-log in AZURE_DEVOPS. The result of the execution will be generated in an EXCEL file. Is there a method that can do this?

Comment: Are you able to see the deploy result in the log of SSIS Deploy Task?

Comment: I'm sorry this question makes no sense. Which log are you trying to capture? The execution log or the deployment log? By back-log do you mean you want to create a task in your DevOps ticket backlog? The result of execution will be generated in an excel file? Do you mean you want to be able to open the log in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could see the deploy result in the log of SSIS Deploy Task, you can add a powershell task after SSIS Deploy Task, then use [RSET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the log and add the result to an Excel file.